# Oracle : Error at line 28: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “end-of-file”

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem and i cant figure it out. It shows....

> Error at line 28: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> begin end function pragma procedure
>
> 1. CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY check_emp_pkg
> 2. IS
> 3. PROCEDURE chk_hiredate
> 4. (p_date IN employees.hire_date%TYPE)

this is my code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY check_emp_pkg 
IS 
  PROCEDURE chk_hiredate 
    (p_date IN employees.hire_date%TYPE) 
    IS BEGIN 
      IF MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, p_date) > g_max_length_of_service * 12 THEN 
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20200, 'Invalid Hiredate'); 
      END IF; 
  END chk_hiredate; 
  PROCEDURE chk_dept_mgr 
    (p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE, 
    p_mgr IN employees.manager_id%TYPE) 
    IS BEGIN
      DECLARE
        v_mgr_id departments.manager_id%TYPE;
      BEGIN
       SELECT manager_id INTO v_mgr_id
       FROM departments;
       IF p_mgr = v_mgr_id THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Success');
       ELSE
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20200, 'Manager ID is not a match');
       END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Manager does not exist');
  END chk_dept_mgr;
END check_emp_pkg;
```

I have no idea why i am getting the error!

Comment: I believe that the IS under the procedure is only needed when it is a standalone procedure. Also, you have already ran the package SPEC, right?

Comment: Yes the package SPEC has been ran and created.  The IS under the procedure from what i have seen is fine. I have googled and its been there in packages.  IDK where the error is. And thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `begin` and `declare` in the second procedure. This part:

```
  PROCEDURE chk_dept_mgr 
    (p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE, 
    p_mgr IN employees.manager_id%TYPE) 
    IS BEGIN
      DECLARE
        v_mgr_id departments.manager_id%TYPE;
      BEGIN
       SELECT manager_id INTO v_mgr_id
       ...
```

Should be just:

```
  PROCEDURE chk_dept_mgr 
    (p_empid IN employees.employee_id%TYPE, 
    p_mgr IN employees.manager_id%TYPE) 
    IS
      v_mgr_id departments.manager_id%TYPE;
    BEGIN
     SELECT manager_id INTO v_mgr_id
     ...
```

You can kind of see from the indentation that your blocks have got out of alignment. You've started an inner block when you didn't really need one, and not ended it properly. You could add an `end` after the `end if` instead, but that inner block still wouldn't be adding anything useful.